# how to insert date as UTC in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I have inserted 2 PM as currentTime.

In local mongodb : 
currentTime : 2018-02-02T08:30:00.000Z

On server mongodb :
currentTime : 2018-02-02T14:00:00.000Z

currentTime field type is 'date'.

mongo v3.6

I am using loopback js in backend. In model this is the field and type.

```
 "currentTime": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": false
    },
```

Where is the problem I am not able to debug ?

Could someone say what will be the reason that converts date on server differently ?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the date?

Comment: @deceze, I have just updated few more details in my query have look.

Comment: "what will be the reason that converts date on server differently" - if I were to guess, the machine's timezone is different between your localhost and the remote db host.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes, my remote machine is on AWS. Could you help , how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @uday214125: physical location of the machines is irrelevant. I meant the timezone setting of the operating system. Make sure they are the same (on your local machine and the db server). This might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/138423/286115

Answer (score 0):

I solved by UTC conversion while insertion and display in browser like this.

While insertion , using moment : `currentTime.utc().format();`

While displaying :

```
 new Date('2018-02-02T14:00:00.000Z').toUTCString();
   ==>"Fri, 02 Feb 2018 14:00:00 GMT"
```